# Why this basis make the matrix with respect to this basis diagonal for the given linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In this question c) ii)[image: question]

Having found the matrix of T with respect to B, in order to find a basis C such that T with respect to C is diagonal, it is necessary to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for [T]b and use those to find [T]c as illustrated by this solution:
[image: solution]

However, I am confused as to why [T]c is indeed diagonal.
Taking the last vector in the basis C:

T(x+1) = T(1) + T(x) = (1+x+x^2) + (2x + x^2)
       = 1 + 3x + 2x^2
       = 2(x^2-1) + 3(x+1)

Then surely the last column vector of [T]c should be (0,2,3) transposed.
And this would mean [T]c is not diagonal.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is wrong. The final eigenpolynomial of $T$ is $x+x^2$, not $1+x$. They did get the right vector $(0,1,1)^T$, but probably got the order of $B$ wrong when translating it back to a polynomial.